# Find values that don't have a second value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a list of column A where there isn't a specific value in column B as well as any other value in Column B.

Example:

```
COLUMN A        COLUMN B
LEFT            ALPHA
LEFT            BETA
LEFT            CHARLIE
RIGHT           BETA
RIGHT           CHARLIE
UP              ALPHA
UP              CHARLIE
DOWN            ALPHA
```

I want to know all Column A where there is an Alpha and at least one other value for Column A.

- Left has an Alpha and another value that is not Alpha so it would be included.
- Right doesn't have an Alpha so excluded.
- Up has an Alpha and another value that is not Alpha so it would be included.
- Down has Alpha but no other values and is excluded.

This can populate a list on another worksheet that would be best. I think I have to go the VBA route but I am unsure where to start.

Comment: Do you need to keep only 1 `LEFT` or 3?

Comment: I just need to know that Left meets or doesnt meet the criteria. So ideally the new worksheet would have each distinct value from column A and whether or not it meets the criteria or not.

Comment: So the result you want is something like `(LEFT, T), (RIGHT, F), (UP, T), (DOWN, F)`?

Comment: Exactly, Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses COUNTIFS. Adjust sheet names to your set up if necessary. I should add that you will need a header row for your data (for AF) so insert a row if necessary.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, wf As WorksheetFunction, r1 As Range

Set wf = WorksheetFunction

Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
r1.Columns(1).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , Sheet2.Range("A1"), unique:=True

With Sheet2
    For Each r In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If wf.CountIfs(r1.Columns(1), r, r1.Columns(2), "ALPHA") > 0 And _
           wf.CountIfs(r1.Columns(1), r, r1.Columns(2), "<>ALPHA") > 0 Then
            r.Offset(, 1) = "Yes"
        Else
            r.Offset(, 1) = "No"
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way in the copy to do it with a condition? For example if Column D equals Delta then copy it over? All while keeping the Unique:=True

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're asking, but you can add criteria when using AF.

Answer (score 2):

Data and result:

[image] [image]

### Formula in result A1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!A$1:A$8,SMALL(IF(
 MATCH(Data!A$1:A$8,Data!A$1:A$8,0)=ROW(Data!A$1:A$8),ROW(Data!A$1:A$8)),ROW())),"")
```

This is the same as the remove duplicated offered by excel, a formula version. Please press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** to complete the formula.

### Formula in result B1:

```
=AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(Data!A$1:A$8&Data!B$1:B$8=A1&"ALPHA"))>0,
 COUNTIF(Data!A$1:A$8,A1)>1)
```

Just some simple criteria judgments. We build a list of combination of column A and column B. That is `LEFTALPHA, LEFTBETA, LEFTCHARLIE, RIGHTBETA....` so that we can search for `LEFTALPHA` is exist or not. And the second criteria is find out the target is single or multiple.

Comment: B1 Formula using COUNTIFS: `=AND(COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,A1,Data!B:B,"ALPHA")>0,COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,A1,Data!B:B,"<>ALPHA")>0)` Then full columns can be used.